# Check if a Popen subprocess finished on Linux - Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I do have a code that runs the same python script with different arguments at the same time in different Shell windows.

The following code do this, but I need do monitor if any subprocess created have finished its execution, and then stop all other subprocesses running, how can I do this monitoring on Linux?

I have tried to check using .wait() and .poll(), but these changes their states after the gnome terminal open, instead of change after the script running on the new terminal ends

```
import subprocess
import shlex

if __name__ == '__main__':

    arg_list = ["gnome-terminal -- python3 teste.py ./get_data/datasets/training_out.xlsx 140.10.61.1 0 2 102 4 OUTPUT 0 632 MEMORY 0 3885 1 0",
            "gnome-terminal -- python3 teste.py ./get_data/datasets/training_out2.xlsx 140.10.61.1 0 2 102 1 OUTPUT 0 272 MEMORY 0 3885 1 1",
            "gnome-terminal -- python3 teste.py ./get_data/datasets/training_in.xlsx 140.10.61.1 0 2 102 2 INPUT 0 632 MEMORY 0 3885 1 2",
            "gnome-terminal -- python3 teste.py ./get_data/datasets/training_in2.xlsx 140.10.61.1 0 2 102 2 INPUT 0 272 MEMORY 0 3885 1 3",
            "gnome-terminal -- python3 teste.py ./get_data/datasets/training_in3.xlsx 140.10.61.1 0 2 102 1 INPUT 0 274 MEMORY 0 3885 1 4"             
            ]

    p1 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(arg_list[0]))

    p2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(arg_list[1]))

    p3 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(arg_list[2]))

    p4 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(arg_list[3]))

    p5 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(arg_list[4]))
```

Comment: When I use wait() and poll() it seems to check if the command 'gnome-terminal' is complete instead of the whole line

Comment: I think you looking for this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269146/wait-until-gnome-terminal-ends

Comment: Thanks, this article helped me to check if the subprocesses are still running. But i'm not able to suspend them

Comment: You want to kill all subprocess if one of them has finished right ?

Comment: I just want to suspend them. But when I run the command 'p2.suspend()', for example, nothing seems to happen

Comment: `Popen` object has no `suspend()` method. I am just curiosity why do you need to open a gnome-terminal window ?